# Livewire component disappears if validation fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with `livewire` in a modal form. In the example below I have a text field and if I submit a modal form an error message appears nicely. But if I try to replace the `text field` with a `dropdown select` item, it disappears. Everything looks ok in a `model` also, the blade file is pretty much the same.

Working with a text field:

```
<div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="textValidationModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" wire:ignore.self>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Text Validation Modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="text" class="form-label">Text</label>
                            <input wire:model="text" type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter text">
                            @error('text') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And code with a select item which does not work:

```
<div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="textValidationModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" wire:ignore.self>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Text Validation Modal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="text" class="form-label">Text</label>
                            <select
                                    id="text"
                                    class="selectpicker w-100"
                                    data-style="btn-default"
                                    data-show-subtext="true"
                                    placeholder="Please select..."
                                    wire:model="text"

                            >
                                <option  data-subtext="" value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option  data-subtext="Code1" value="1" >code1</option>
                                <option  data-subtext="Code2" value="2" >code2</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('text') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it looks in a modal after disappears: [image]

Comment: Hi. Try to remove class `selectpicker` for beginning.

Comment: @ArthurShlain Yes you are right. The dropdown not disappearing anymore. But how is this related? Why I can't have a class on this element?

Comment: I think your livewire component appears asynchronously, so your select inside is not properly initialized.